# Right values not calculated in spark window function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've the following table
[Initial Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feCPs.png)

I need to transform usign Spark scala window functions as below
[Transformed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQEoA.png)

The code used is here. I'm not able to get required AssignmentId values

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val data = Seq(
    Row("1","E19819","1","2019-11-03","A6"),
    Row("2","E19819","1","2019-11-02","A4"),
    Row("3","E19819","1","2019-11-01","A3"),
    Row("4","E19819","0","2019-11-01","A1"),
    Row("5","E19819","0","2019-11-01","A2"),
    Row("6","E19819","1","2019-10-28","A5")



)
val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("UniqueId", StringType, true),
    StructField("CustomerId", StringType, true),
    StructField("Backoffice", StringType, true),
    StructField("TxDateBase", StringType, true),
    StructField("AssignmtId_orig", StringType, true)
  )
)

val dfCustData = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  schema
).
  withColumn("TxDate", to_date(col("TxDateBase")))
 .withColumn("AssignmtId", when ( col("Backoffice")===1, col("AssignmtId_orig")).otherwise(null))
 .drop("TxDateBase")

val cols = Seq("AssignmtId")
val w1 = Window
  .partitionBy("CustomerId")
  .orderBy($"TxDate",$"Backoffice".desc,$"UniqueId".desc)
  .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

val w2 = Window
  .partitionBy("CustomerId")
  .orderBy($"TxDate",$"Backoffice".desc,$"UniqueId".desc)
  .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

val dfCustTransformedData = cols .foldLeft(dfCustData)((dfCustupdated, columnName) =>
      dfCustupdated.withColumn(columnName,
    coalesce(col(columnName),
      first(columnName, ignoreNulls = true).over(w2),
      last(columnName, ignoreNulls = true).over(w1)
    ))
)
dfCustTransformedData.orderBy($"TxDate".desc,$"Backoffice".desc, $"uniqueId").show()
```

For the rows with uniqueid 4&5 , the AssignmentId should be set to A3. Right now it is set to A4

Comment: please post a reproducible example using a programmatically created dataframe

Comment: Roth,Added executable code